# Element of an array doesn't change when using the UPDATE cmd (jsonb data type)

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

First of all I'd like to say that I don't have much experience but I started learning dbs after having a couple of subjects related to dbs at my university (so please keep that in mind while you're reading this).

---

I want to change a single element of a nested array with the UPDATE command.
I used dbfiddle to test out if what I am doing would work before putting anything into the real database as to not make any unnecessary mistakes. I don't know what went wrong since dbfiddle clearly says that "1 row has been affected" but I don't see any changes in my nested array.
Here is what I have written in dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ecc2329efea6af28636b3537d46b6c01
I'd be grateful if someone could clarify what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `WHERE id = 2` doesn't select any row, because the one you insert has `id = 1`.  The checkmark in dbfiddle only means "success", it doesn't indicate that something was updated. If you ran this in a different SQL tool, you'd get a feedback that "0 rows" were affected. Additionally, `podaci ->> 'firstName'` is also "false", as `podaci` contains an array, so the `->>` can't be used here. This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model....

Comment: And `jsonb_set()` requires an array index position as part of the second parameter, e.g. `'{1, "lastName"}'` - but finding the correct index to be used is quite complicated

Comment: So using jsonb to do this was a bad idea?
What do you mean by normalized data model? Would you care to elaborate on that?